# Python XLWings Sheets collection exceptiion raising

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, xlwings

I am confused by some behavior of the XLWings package for python I wonder about? If I am trying to find a worksheet in a workbook, but I don't know the exact name (international shared xl workbook with various sheet names...), I would assume I could iterate over the sheets and test if its the right one. In normal python I would do something like:

```py
sheets = {'Not_Datos': 1, 'Still_Not': 2, 'Datos': 3} # Pretend data
    
def get_worksheet():
    possible_worksheet_names = ['Data', 'Datos', 'Daten']
    
    for possible_worksheet_name in possible_worksheet_names:
        try:
            return sheets[possible_worksheet_name]
        except KeyError:
            continue
    
    # -- If no worksheet is found...
    raise Exception('Error, Can not find worksheet.')

worksheet = get_worksheet()
print(worksheet) # >>> 3
```

and this would work fine. In the example above, I would get '3' as the result.

But in XLwings I am not getting that same behavior. If I do something like:

```py
import xlwings as xw
xl = xw.books.active

sheets = xl.sheets

def get_worksheet():
    possible_worksheet_names = ['Data', 'Datos', 'Daten']
    
    for possible_worksheet_name in possible_worksheet_names:
        try:
            return sheets[possible_worksheet_name]
        except:
            continue
    
    # -- If no worksheet is found...
    raise Exception("Error, can't find worksheet")

worksheet = get_worksheet()
print(worksheet) # >>> CommandError ?
```

instead of getting the expected result, I get a Command Error telling me the sheet can't be found?

```
OSERROR: -1728
MESSAGE: The object you are trying to access does not exist
COMMAND: app(pid=5580).workbooks['PHPP_V9.6a_ES_Vacio.xlsx'].worksheets['Data'].name.get()
```

One wrinkle is that adding a print statement inline will cause the expected raise...continue? So if I do:

```py
import xlwings as xw
xl = xw.books.active

sheets = xl.sheets

def get_worksheet():
    possible_worksheet_names = ['Data', 'Datos', 'Daten']

    for possible_worksheet_name in possible_worksheet_names:
        try:
            worksheet =  sheets[possible_worksheet_name]
            print(worksheet) #<----- when this is added, now it works?
            return worksheet
        except:
            continue

    # -- If no worksheet is found...
    raise Exception("Error, can't find worksheet")

worksheet = get_worksheet()
print(worksheet) # >>> <Sheet [PHPP_V9.6a_ES_Vacio.xlsx]Datos>
```

then in that case it works as expected?

So I suppose it must have something to do with the return value or the way the CommandError is getting raised / passed? Calling print causes the exception to get raised, while the normal return does not? Does that seem right?

Is there preferred way to find a worksheet in a workbook, if the exact name is not known ahead of time? How would you search through the workbook in a way that avoided whatever trouble is happening here?

Very curious? Thanks!

---

Environment:

- Macbook 2021, Apple M1 Max
- OS 12.4 (Monterey)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the sheets in a workbook before attempting to open any by

```
xlwings.Book(<workbook>).sheets
```

So you can iterate through the available sheets and check those against a list and open any matches.

```
import xlwings as xw


wb = xw.Book('foo.xlsx')
possible_worksheet_names = ['Data', 'Datos', 'Daten']

for sheet in wb.sheets:
    print(sheet.name)
    if sheet.name in possible_worksheet_names:
        ws = wb.sheets[sheet.name]
        print("Sheet " + str(sheet.name) + " opened.")
        # Do Something
    else:
        print("No sheet in workbook matched list!")
```